# Facebook API. Pull Custom Audience statistics from the Audience Insights

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-fql

Is it possible to pull (programmatically) demographic statistics about your custom audience from the Facebook Audience Insights? Spent some time on investigation of this question (SDKs, Graph API, google & stackoverflow searches), but it haven't worked for me.

Audience Insights Demographics:

[image]

Any hint or direction will help a lot! Many thanks in advance